# Remove combinations from permutations in Python

Tags: python

I make a list of the permutations between the number of fruits available and the number of farmers. In the permutations it enters the (1,2,..,max_number of fruits) and number of farmers(3). This is the code  I use:

```
action_list = list(permutations(no_fruits(list), no_farmers(just a number)))
```

Imagine there are 3 fruits are 3 farmers. Fruit number 1 is an apple, number 2 is another apple and number 3 a mango. The information of which fruit it is is inside the object 1.fruit= apple for example.I have already a lis that says which numbers have the same fruits. We have these 6 combinations:
(1,2,3)
(1,3,2)
(2,1,3)
(2,3,1)
(3,1,2)
(3,2,1)

But now I don't want to differenciate apple 1 from apple 2. So the final output should be:
(1,2,3)
(1,3,2)
(3,1,2)

How can I remove the other combinations? In other words, how can I remove the
combinations where only fruit number 1 and number 2 swap places with each other?

Other relevant information:
The number of farmers can be superior to the number of available fruits. In that case there would be some farmers that wouldn't have a fruit and would be represented as '-'. here is an example:

(1,2,-)

This means farmer 3 doesn't have a fruit, while farmer 1 and 2 have fruits 1 and 2, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't yet grasped to the fullest. However, here is an updated code to handle mismatch between fruits and farmers but requires two iterables:

```
def customZip(*obj):
    while any(obj):
        yield ([i.pop(0) if i else '-' for i in obj])

def permutation(fruits, farmers):
    populate = []
    for i in customZip(fruits, farmers):
        populate.append(i)

    def _permutation(obj, _len):
        if len(obj) == 1:
            yield obj
        else:
            l = []
            for i in range(len(obj)):
                for j in _permutation(obj[:i] + obj[i+1:], _len):
                    alt = obj[i:i+1] + j
                    if len(alt) != _len:
                        yield alt
                    else:
                        res = [i[0] for i in alt]
                        if res not in l:
                            l.append(res)
                            yield ([i[1] for i in alt], res)

    for j in _permutation(populate, len(populate)):
        yield j

for i in permutation(fruits, farmers):
    print(i)
```

```
#1
farmers = [1, 2, 3]
fruits = ['apple', 'apple', 'melon']

([1, 2, 3], ['apple', 'apple', 'melon'])
([1, 3, 2], ['apple', 'melon', 'apple'])
([3, 1, 2], ['melon', 'apple', 'apple'])
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

```
#2
farmers = [1, 2, 3]
fruits = ['apple', 'melon']

([1, 2, 3], ['apple', 'melon', '-'])
([1, 3, 2], ['apple', '-', 'melon'])
([2, 1, 3], ['melon', 'apple', '-'])
([2, 3, 1], ['melon', '-', 'apple'])
([3, 1, 2], ['-', 'apple', 'melon'])
([3, 2, 1], ['-', 'melon', 'apple'])
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

Comment: This helps but don't want the "apple","melon" written because I don't know them beforehand. For example in [3,2,1] 3 is the fruit given to farmer 1, fruit 2 to farmer 2 and fruit 1 to farmer 3. So one possible input is that the number of food is different that the number of farmer. So in the permutation len(nm) i would actually want the len(numer of farmers) while nm would be the number of fruits available. That is this doesn't work for cases when there are more farmers thank fruits

Comment: Such information should be added to the main question, and also in case of latter how the fruits should be spreaded to the farmers? Please add it too and possible other critical information as necessary to make your question more clear.

Comment: Thanks for your inpu. I'll add it

Comment: Sorry I wasn't completely clear, but inside I don't want the description of the fruit. That would be the term of comparison between numbers. like if 1.fruit==1.fruit then they are the same. So the input in the permutation function would be :[1,2,3,4, (...)],numberof farmers